# What linear transformation minimizes the Kolmogorov–Smirnov distance between two sets of points?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, test-equating

Suppose we have two sets of real-valued points $X_1, \dots, X_m$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$. We want to find the linear transformation that makes the distributions [look alike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating). If we want them to have the same (mean, standard deviation) or the same (minimum, maximum), we simply solve a system of two linear equations. But how do we find the linear transformation on $Y$ that minimizes the [two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)?

Comment: Why the restriction to a ***linear*** transformation?

Comment: If the transformation can be non-linear, the solution is simple and already known: equipercentile equating, which also mentioned in the Wikipedia entry for equating.

Comment: Another reason: equipercentile equating might overfit if we're doing this for the purpose of domain adaptation, and if our knowledge about the data generation process indicates that the true transformation is approximately linear.

Comment: This is an interesting question; right now I don't see a good way to do it beyond numerical methods. It's not hard to get a reasonable approximate solution and then "head downhill". The minimum is not going to be unique in general; there'll tend to be a thin region of values with the same minimum value of $D$.